# How to change bg color if condition in map function using jsx?

Tags: reactjs

i have an object of data where i want to change the color of a div on condition base

```
 <Col className="mainbody">                      
      {items.map(data => <CardPanel className="location" 
                         key={data.parkingID}>
                        <div onClick={() => 
                          this.handleClick(data.parkingArea)} >                                                     
                         {data.parkingArea}
                       {data.status == "booked" ? style="color changed to 
                              red" :style= "color changed to red"}
                      <Icon>directions_car</Icon>                               
                        </div>
                    </CardPanel>)}
```

here in {data.status} i want to check the condition if status is "booked" then change bgcolor "red"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do so.

In the following code snippets, let's assume the condition is declared beforehand:

```
const condition = data.status === 'booked';
```

**Style way**

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: condition ? "red" : "white" }} />
```

Using double brackets will cause your component to re-render a lot because of the object's reference changing all the time. There are a lot of utilities to prevent that such as [fast-memoize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-memoize).

**Class Way**

There are several ways to concatenate classNames conditionally, here is one using ES6 :

```
<div className={[
    classNames.card,
    ...(cond && [classNames.booked])
  ]} 
/>
```

There are also some libraries such as [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) for the code clarity's sake. I personally use a custom library to be able to write it like this:

```
<div className={cn.concat(classNames.card, [classNames.booked, cond])} />
```

In scss, it will allow you to declare your style as this :

```
.card {
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color .2s ease;

    &.booked {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either inline styles (https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)
Or assign class name for each case and add a css class for that. For the later option, you can use classnames npm pkg (https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)